# Binary classification of phone numbers

Tags: binary-data, text-mining

I want to classify numbers that are entered manually as either correct or incorrect.

An example of the dataframe is shown below:

```
head(data$NUMBER, n = 15)

 [1] "+38875201543"   NA              "070 612 064"   "075 295 051"   "078 390 180"   "0000000000000" "070 352929"   
 [8] NA              NA              "076 424 934"   NA              "нема тел"      "070-523-498"   "072 24 20 38" 
[15] "нема тел"
```

I can do a pretty good job with regular expressions in seperating most of the incorrect numbers. For instance, if a number contains text/NA/More Than XY number of digits, than flag as incorrect.

But I was thinking more I could do a better job with some boosting/bagging algorithm.

Any suggestions of what might be the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than focus on the algorithms at play (although tree-based methods may be particularly suited to the type of discontinuous response we expect in this case), I would focus on feature generation that provide numeric representations of different factors a human uses to make this judgement.  Examples:

`1) Has letters or not
2) Has plus sign
3) length of string
4) country of phone number / area code
5) unique character types (digit, punctuation, alpha) etc. in string.`

Using some of the above / other similar types of ideas, I'd bet you can get high accuracy with a number of supervised ML techniques.

Comment: Yes, I feagured throughout the weekend that an unsupervised model such as k-means would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Prometheus.  Cool user name.  Unsupervised may also work and avoid having to have labeled training set, as long as you have good features => a good representation of distance.